# Simplifying jQuery DOM request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to simplify my code into one whole step function. Since it has the same attributes & functions, I don't know what exactly the call function to merge it all in one action.

```
$('a[data-user="add"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list-unstyled li').removeClass('active');
  $('section.col-lg-8').replaceWith(formAdd);
  $('.form-custom').load('includes/pages/admin/admin-user-add.php');
  subHash = this.hash;
});

$('a[data-user="settings"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list-unstyled li').removeClass('active');
  $('section.col-lg-8').replaceWith(formAdd);
  $('.form-custom').load('includes/pages/admin/admin-user-settings.php');
  subHash = this.hash;
});
```

I thought including it both with separate comma, will be a great idea but it is not. it default the view to my first load.

Comment: you mean the whole codes of this script ? or the whole page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grabbing both selectors separated by a comma, and then using jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to fill in the correct admin page:

```
$('a[data-user="settings"],a[data-user="add"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list-unstyled li').removeClass('active');
  $('section.col-lg-8').replaceWith(formAdd);
  $('.form-custom').load('includes/pages/admin/admin-user-'+$(this).attr('data-user')+'.php');
  subHash = this.hash;
});
```